# Store form-data in php-session and do action to second page

Tags: php, forms, session, action

the script works fine unless i do an action, like: action='/page2/'.
I´m able to write the form data in a session and i´m able to load the data from the session when i manually open the second page. But when i paste the the link in the form, with action='', it just opens the second page without showing the data.

**FIRST PAGE**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['pname'] = $_POST['pname'];
?>

<form action='' method='post'> <section class='colh col-4'>
   <input type='text' name='pname' id='pname' value=''/>
   <input type='submit' name='psubmit' value='SUBMIT'/>
</form>
```

**SECOND PAGE**

```
 session_start();
 $pname = $_SESSION['pname'];
 echo "pname:".$pname;
```

Comment: you should start session on second page also by putting session_start();

Answer (score 1):

If you set the action to "page2" you won't be able store the form data in session, form data will be **posted** to the "page2".

If you want to get the data on "page2" from session you have to post the data to the current page first and store the data in session and load the "page2" using header("Location:page2");

make sure you check the page is actually posted by check the $_POST variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)){
$_SESSION['pname'] = $_POST['pname'];
header("Location:page2.php");
}
?>

<form action='' method='post'> <section class='colh col-4'>
   <input type='text' name='pname' id='pname' value=''/>
   <input type='submit' name='psubmit' value='SUBMIT'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SECOND PAGE -**

```
session_start();

$pname = $_SESSION['pname'];
echo "pname:".$pname;
```

add `session_start()` on `SECOND PAGE` also

Comment: sorry, i just forgot to post it here. it´s already in the code.